# Задача Автопроверка на Массивы объеков в JS

Tags: javascript

ЗАДАЧА:
Напиши функцию calculateTotalPrice(productName), которая принимает один параметр productName - название товара. Функция должна вернуть общую стоимость (цена * количество) товара с таким именем из массива products
Условие и мое решение ниже. Результат не возвращается. - подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не понимаю?:

```js
const products = [
  { name: "Radar", price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: "Scanner", price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: "Droid", price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: "Grip", price: 1200, quantity: 9 },
];

console.log(calculateTotalPrice(products))

function calculateTotalPrice(productName) {
  // Change code below this line
for (const product of products) {
  if (productName = product.name) {}
 }
   return (products.price * products.quantity);
  // Change code above this line
}
```

Comment: **1)** куда это должно вернуться? .... **2)** что такое `products.price` и `products.quantity`? .... **3)** что это за условие бестолковое `if (productName = product.name) {}` ? ...... **4)** и почему в условии одно `=` ?  ....  **5)** *"мое решение ниже"* --- что это за решение такое. объясните что вы делали, ваши **полные рассуждения**   ...... **6)** вам надо понимать ещё, что продукта с указанным именем может быть несколько штук в массиве, а не одна штука всегда

Comment: function calculateTotalPrice(productName) {
  // Change code below this line
for (const product of products)
  if (product.name === productName) 
    return (product.price * product.quantity);
  return 0;
    // Change code above this line
}

Comment: Вот это решение в комментарии правильное (если учитывать только то, что указанный товар будет встречаться только единожды).

Comment: Спассибо за "взбучку"))) вроде понял логику